# How can I sort this list alphabetically, need assistance

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

1.I'm trying to sort a list of songs alphabetically by title but all that is happening is the list is put in reverse order and then outputted.

```
public void sort()
{
  //create a pointer to hold the temp for switching
  MusicHW02 temp;

  //two nested loops. Go through entire list less 1 
  for (int index = 0;index< count -1;index++) {

    /*inner for loop to go through list starting with next index 
     *to see if smaller 
     */
    for(int index2= index +1; index2<count; index2++) {

      //Sort method to compare Strings
      if(collection[index2].getTitle().compareTo(collection[index].getTitle())<0);{
        temp = collection[index2];
        collection[index2] = collection[index]; 
        collection[index] = temp;
      }//END OF IF STATEMENT
    }//END OF INNER FOR LOOP
  }//END OF OUTER FOR LOOP
}//END OF SORT METHOD
```

Comment: Remove that semicolon after the `if` condition.

Comment: Can't you use Comparator to do your sorting?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semi-colon at the end of the if statement because it will be treated as a n empty statement

```
if(collection[index2].getTitle().compareTo(collection[index].getTitle())<0);{}
```

to

```
if(collection[index2].getTitle().compareTo(collection[index].getTitle())<0){}
```

Simply why don't you use

```
Collections.sort(someList);
```

or

```
Arrays.sort(someArray);
```

or something like this

```
String arr[] ={"abc","def","adf","acb"};
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(arr),new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a Comparator. This will give you the flexibility to sort however you want. I threw this together but it should help you do what you want. This does a bubble sort btw. Using a comparator you could also convert them to all upper/lower case before the sort so that you will always have them in the right order even if the string cases's don't match.

```
Coparator<String> songComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
   public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
      if (str1 == null) {
         return 0;
      }
      return (str2 != null) ? str1.compareTo(str2) : 1;

   }

}

Arrays.sort(<collection you want to sort>, songComparator);
```

Here is a good list of examples http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/